# Weyl group of orthogonal group

Tags: algebraic-groups, root-systems

My question is why a particular element of the Weyl group of $O(8)$ seems to contradict a theorem about root systems.  But to tell you the particular element I have to tell you specifically how I'm thinking of $O(8)$.

Consider $8 \times 8$ matrices and let
$$K = \begin{bmatrix} &&&&&&& 1 \\ &&&&&& 1 \\ &&&&& 1 \\ &&&& 1 \\ &&& 1 \\ && 1 \\ & 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
I define the orthogonal group $O(8)$ to be $O(8) = \{A \in GL_8 \mid A^{\mathrm{tr}}KA = K\}$.  These are the matrices such that taking the transpose across the other diagonal (the one that goes top-right to bottom-left) yields the inverse.

Diagonal matrices
$$D(t_1, t_2, t_3, t_4) = \begin{bmatrix} t_1 \\ & t_2 \\ && t_3 \\ &&& t_4 \\ &&&& t_4^{-1} \\ &&&&& t_3^{-1} \\ &&&&&& t_2^{-1} \\ &&&&&&& t_1^{-1} \end{bmatrix}$$
give a maximal torus $T$.  I let $e_i \in X(T)$ be the character $D(t_1, t_2, t_3, t_4) \mapsto t_i$.  Then $O(8)$ is type $D_4$ with roots $\Phi = \{\pm e_i \pm e_j \mid i < j\}$.  Choose simple roots $\alpha_i = e_i - e_{i + 1}$ for $i = 1,2,3$ and $\alpha_4 = e_3 + e_4$.

**Now my question:** Consider the matrix
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ & 1 \\ && 1 \\ &&& 0 & 1 \\ &&& 1 & 0 \\ &&&&& 1 \\ &&&&&& 1 \\ &&&&&&& 1\end{bmatrix}$$
Clearly $A \in O(8)$ and $AD(t_1, t_2, t_3, t_4)A^{-1} = D(t_1, t_2, t_3, t_4^{-1})$ so $A$ represents a *non-zero* element of the Weyl group $W = N_{O(8)}(T)/C_{O(8)}(T)$.  But the action of $A$ on $X(T)$ fixes $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2$ and swaps $\alpha_3, \alpha_4$.  This contradicts the theorem that Weyl groups act simply transitively on the Weyl chambers.  So something must be wrong.  The only thing I can think of is that $A$ lies in $O(8)$ but not in $SO(8)$; maybe something I'm doing here works only for connected reductive groups but I have no clue what that something might be.

Comment: Are you sure those matrices give a maximal torus? It seems strange that the maximal torus should be contained in $SO(8)$.

Comment: I think that's standard, $SO(8)$ is the identity component of $O(8)$ and tori are connected.

Comment: the fact that $A\notin SO(8)$ is the problem. One should really use connected groups. That's how the Weyl group is defined.

Comment: Something doesn't add up. Weyl groups of type $D_n$ only contain those signed permutations that have an even number of sign changes. Looks like you do need to specify $\det=1$.

Comment: maybe to add a bit of perspective: If $G$ is a (connected) reductive group, $T\subset G$ a Cartan torus, $K$ a finite (say) group acting on $G$ by automorphisms, in such a way that $T$ is invariant under this action. Now consider the semidirect product of $G$ with $K$. If you treat is a non-connected reductive group then $K$ seems to become a part of the Weyl group. But it is not. One needs connected groups.